# Enable bluetooth on Dell Latitude E5450 laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bluetooth, dell-latitude

I have Linux and Windows 10 installed on my laptop. Linux sees my Bluetooth device, however I can't find one under Windows.
I am trying to solve problem with Dell Command Update

[image: Screenshot - Dell Command Update]

It downloads something and runs, but after next check it asks to run the same procedure. I don't know if this is related to Bluetooth or not.

I see several problems in device manager, but I don't know if it is related to Bluetooth and I have no idea how to fix them:

[image: Screenshot - Device Manager]

[image: Screenshot - Manually updated package]

How to enable Bluetooth in system?

UPD

I was trying to update driver manually.
[image]

But this did not help.
It is strange that Dell Command still offers me to download and install the same driver even when I have it already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install the Bluetooth drivers manually from Dell website: [Latitude E5450 drivers](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-e5450-laptop/drivers/advanced). From there take the network category and the Intel 8260/7265/3165/7260 Bluetooth Driver.

Here is a direct link to the correct driver: http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03635699M/1/Network_Driver_N7VN8_WN32_18.1.1611.3223_A11.EXE

-AirPett

Comment: This not helped.
Strange that Dell Command still offers me to download and install the same driver. Mor details in UPD

Comment: Ok, did this happen after Windows 10 upgrade?

Comment: Currently I run Windows 10, but I didn't noticed when it has happened